# Integration tests with Maven in a Spring project

Tags: spring, integration-testing, maven-3

The question is how can I use different properties files for integration testing. Detailed explanation follows.

I'm trying to do in container integration tests with Maven, using `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. The project uses Spring and JPA. At present what I've figured out is the following:

- Unit test class names follow the pattern *Test and run with `mvn test` by `maven-surefire-plugin`
- Integration test class names follow the pattern *IT and run with `mvn verify` by `maven-failsafe-plugin`
- With executions I can trigger to start and stop tomcat and deploy the war file

All of this works and when I run `mvn verify` Tomcat is started.

However instead of using a regular database, I would like to use an in memory database. My database configuration is defined in the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties` loaded through `context:property-placeholder`.

I tried to define an alternative file in `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties`, but is ignored. I know that is possible to define system properties within `tomcat7-maven-plugin`, but I don't know how to use them to trigger loading of different properties files.

My `tomcat7-maven-plugin` configuration is the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/processing</path>
        <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
        <systemProperties>
            <example.value.1>alpha</example.value.1>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Properties are loaded by `context-main.xml` with the following line:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
```

I load context configuration from `web.xml` with the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/context-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Any suggestion on how to load alternative properties file for testing?

Comment: the `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties` will be taken in account in the normal tests, but not in the failsave tests, because the failsave tests are based on the normal `war`, and this does NOT include the test src or test resources

Comment: Right, I suspected so, now I'm experimenting with profiles and `maven-antrun-plugin` to copy the modified property file directly in the build folder. If anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, is with Maven profiles and the ant plugin. I suspect that is not the most elegant way, and I'm open to listen for better solution, but for now it solves my problem.

A profile is a way to have a different Maven configuration depending on command line arguments, so in my case to run the integration tests, I run the command `mvn -Pintegration clean verify`. Here `integration` is the name of the profile, and is defined in `pom.xml`, after the `properties` as follows:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>standard</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <echo>Copying test database.properties to ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/spring/</echo>
                                    <copy file="src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties"
                                        todir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/spring/" verbose="true" overwrite="true" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Using `mvn clean package` will instead use the standard profile. It's interesting to mention that profiles can also be defined outside the pom, in .m2/settings.xml

See also: [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) -- Notice that the `overwrite` parameter in the copy is essential or it will work only at random, and is not mentioned in the linked document.